# Is there a way to get the OSX battery icon to display both percentage and time?

Tags: snow-leopard, battery, power, menu-bar

I am working on a 2006 MacBook with Snow Leopard.

The battery level indicator has the option to show **Time *or* Percentage** remaining. I would like to show ***both***.

[image]

Is there a way to enable this?
or
Can you recommend an app that will do it?

Comment: I've been searching for weeks for a **horizontal** battery menulet that is coloured coded. Please, someone make one? I have SlimBatteryMonitor, but there is no adequate horizontal option.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## iStat Menu

offers to display both percentage and Time. http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/

When running SL, you could get the old free version. However, it does not contain the battery menulet: http://mac.brothersoft.com/istat-menus-2.0.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In 2024 the best option IMO is "Energiza - Battery Monitor" (free app in the AppStore).